# tcpdump filter out arp and all stp packets

Tags: filter, tcpdump, arp, stp

I need to capture on an interface with tcpdump and filter out all arp and stp/rstp packets.
I tried this command, which does filter out arp, but I still see rstp packets:

`tcpdump -n -i ens224 not arp and not stp`

Also tried this, still see rstp packets

`tcpdump -n -i ens224 not stp`

What am I doing wrong?

I read this post already but its not helpful in the context of tcpdump, looking for specific syntax:
[how to filter rtsp packets from a pcap file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248195/how-to-filter-rtsp-packets-from-a-pcap-file)

Answer (score 12):

You are not doing wrong. It's about how libpcap and vendors are reading/writing headers. To remove STP 802.1d lines I use this command:

`tcpdump -i eth0 not arp and not llc`

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the well known multicast mac address for each protocol. Look at this table:

https://embeddist.wordpress.com/2015/10/07/well-known-ethernet-multicast-address/
and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#Ethernet

And you can something like this:

(RSTP)

```
tcpdump -n -i <interface> ether host 01:00:0c:cc:cc:cd
```

(CDP)

```
tcpdump -n -i <interface> ether host 01:00:0c:cc:cc:cc
```

(LLDP)

```
tcpdump -n -i <interface> ether host 01:80:c2:00:00:0e
```